# Is there a way(in C++) to create a template class that implements certain functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization, sfinae

I want to create a class that accepts only certain types of template classes. I know that there exists template specialization, but I want my class to accept all templates that implement a specific function, search.

Let's say I have a `class A` as follows:

```
template<class T> //add a restriction that T implements bool search(T)
class A
{
    T t;
    //do something that uses T.search(T x)
    if(t.search(x))
        //Do something
};
```

So basically, I want to create a generic class that works for all classes that have the search functionality. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What you want is concepts, which will (hopefully) come in C++20. Meanwhile, it is more or less possible to do it, but this won't be that clean / simple. What is your use case ?

Comment: I have a searching problem to which I have 5 different solutions. I've coded each solution in a separate cpp file. Now I want to test these solutions and compare their performance, in particular I want to test the search functionality. So I built a generic test class that uses the search function. What I would like to do is plug in the class name of each solution and the test runs on its own and gives me the results.

Comment: `T.search(x)`?  Shouldn't suppose to be `T::search(x)` or something like`T().search(x)`? BTW, your class template will generate an ill-formed code when you instantiate it with a `T` doesn't has a member function `search`. That's also a kind of restriction.

Comment: @Synxis: That can already be done by SFINAE. No need for concepts! But indeed, concepts will make it a lot easier!

Comment: If T has no search function, then attempting to use A<T> will fail to compile. What more restriction would you require?

Comment: @ROX so is it ok to use search without declaring it anyway in the generic template?

Comment: if T implements search its OK, If you try to use a T that does not implement search then you'll get a compile time error. In C# you would have to declare that T had a search by declaring that it implemented a certain interface (declared beforehand to contain search), but you don't need to do the same for C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to create a generic class that works for all classes that have the search functionality. Is there a way to do this?

By example, using `decltype()` as follows

```
template <typename T,
          typename = decltype(std::declval<T>().search(std::declval<T>()))>
class A
 {
 };
```

The following is a full compiling example for a `size()` enabled `class A`

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename = decltype(std::declval<T>().size())>
class A
 {
 };

int main()
 {
   A<std::string>  as;
   //A<int>          ai;  // compilation error
 }
```

There is a drawback in this solution: you can hijack it explicating the second template parameter; by example, the following code compile

```
A<int, void>  ai;
```

To avoid this problem you can use partial specialization as follows

```
template <typename T,
          typename = decltype(std::declval<T>().search(std::declval<T>()))>
class A;

template <typename T>
class A<T>
 {
 };
```